# Why does C not define minimum size for an array?

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior

C standard defines a lot of lower/upper limits (**[translation limits](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.2.4.1.html)**) and imposes an implementation should satisfy  for each translation. Why there's no such minimum limit defined for an array size? The following program is going to compile fine and likely produce runtime error/segfault and would invoke **undefined behaviour**.

```
int main()
{
   int a[99999999];
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<99999999;i++)
   a[i]=i;

   return 0;
}
```

A possible reason could be local arrays are allocated on automatic storage and it depends on the size of the stack frame allocated. But why not a minimum limit like other limits defined by C?

Let's forget about the undefined cases like above. Consider the following:

```
int main()
{
   int a[10];
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   a[i]=i;

   return 0;
}
```

In the above, what gives me the guarantee that the local array (despite a very small one) is going to work as expected and won't cause undefined behaviour due to allocation failure?

Although it's unlikely that an allocation for such a small array would fail on any modern systems. But the C standard doesn't define any requirements to satisfy and compilers don't (at least GCC doesn't) report allocation failures. Only a runtime error/undefined behaviour is possibility. *The hard part is nobody can tell whether an arbitrary sized array is going cause undefined behaviour due to allocation failure.*

Note that I am aware I can use dynamic arrays (via *malloc* & friends) for this purpose and have a better control over allocation failures. I am more interested in why there's no such limit defined for local arrays. Also, global arrays are going to be stored in static storage and is going to increase executable size which compilers can handle.

Comment: "The hard part is nobody can tell whether an arbitrary sized array is going cause undefined behaviour due to allocation failure." - How do you propose this be solved? What minimum would you use?  Keep in mind the variety of platforms C runs on, spanning everything from tiny little microcontrollers with itsy bitsy stacks to 64+ bit architectures with very large stacks. Furthermore, recursion can greatly affect stack availability. If you're prorgamming on C, you generally know your hardware and thus your stack availability.

Comment: @KingsIndian I think solution is to avoid the use of "the stack" in situations which might put unexpected pressure on it - and to know the limits of the execution requirement. It's sort of like an excessive amount of recursion: it will produce UB in some environments much sooner than others.

Comment: @KingsIndian It is well written. I tried to think of a better title, but your last paragraph eliminates such focus :) Hopefully it will stay open as I think there is good information and responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MINIMUM limit is an array of 1 element. Why would you have a "limit" for that? Of course, if you call a function recursively forever, an array of 1 may not fit on the stack, or the call that calls the function next call around may not fit on the stack - the only way to solve that would be to know the size of the stack in the compiler - but the compiler doesn't actually know at that stage how big the stack is - never mind the problems of extremely complex call hierarchies were several different functions call into the same function, possibly with recursion and/or several layers of rather large consumers of stack - how do you size the stack for that - the worst possible case may not be ever encountered, because other things dictate that this doesn't happen - for example, the worst case in one function is only when an input file is empty, but the worst case in another function is when there is lots of data stored in the same file. Lots and lots of variations like this. It's just too unreliable to determine, so sooner or later it would just become guess-work or of lots of false positives.

Consider a program with thousands of functions, all of which call the same logging function that needs a 200 byte array on the stack for temporarily storing the log output. It's called from just about every function from main upwards.

The MAXIMUM for a local variable depends on the size of the stack, which, like I said above, is not something the compiler knows when compiling your code [the linker MAY know, but that's later on]. For global arrays and those allocated on the heap, the limit is "how much memory your process can get", so there's no upper limit there.

There's just no easy way to determine this. And many of the limits provided by the standard is there to guarantee that code can be compiled on "any compiler" as long as your code follows the rules. Be compiled and be able to run to completion is two different things.

int main()
{
    while(1); 
}

will never run to completion - but it will compile in every compiler I know of, and most won't say a thing about there being an infinite loop - it's your choice to do that.

It's also your choice to put large arrays on the stack. And it could well be that the linker is given several gigabytes of stack, in which case it'll be fine - or the stack is 200K, and you can't have  50000 array of integers...

Comment: 127 nested levels may not require any memory (beside the code-space) at all. If you make a lot of nested if/while/switch statements, they don't use up any stackspace, unless there are local variables in them. Obviously, a lot of nest if's and while's and such means some data has to be used, but not necessarily a whole lot. Again, that limit is there to guarantee that if you write code that has (no more than) 127 levels, it can be compiled on any (compliant) compiler. The code may not fit in the 8KB of RAM that the system has, but that's nothing the compiler can do about...

Answer (score 9):

You've already answered your own question; it's due to stack limitation.<sup>*</sup>  Even this might not work:

```
void foo(void) {
    int a;

    ...
}
```

if the `...` is actually a recursive call to `foo`.

In other words, this is nothing to do with arrays, as the same problem affects all local variables.  The standard couldn't enforce a requirement, because in practice that would translate into a requirement for an infinite-sized stack.

---

<sub>* Yes, I know the C standard(s) don't talk about stacks.  But that's the implicit model, in the sense that the standard was really a formalisation of the implementations that existed at the time.</sub>

Comment: but, thats not what he's asking

Comment: Additionally, the stack was just never meant to be the place where you keep large things. It was intended for relatively small things whereas big things were meant for the heap. So if you're trying to allocate gigantic arrays on the stack, you're just using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Then what is he asking?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : he's asking why the standard doesn't require an implementation to support a certain minimum array size in order to be compliant.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: I assumed that followed immediately from my answer!  Namely, it would require an implementation to offer an infinite stack in order to remain compliant.

Comment: @KingsIndian: I think that's really a compile-time limit; i.e. how much nesting must the compiler be able to track before it breaks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : that in itself is indeed an (if not the) answer. Mentioning that explicitly (as you now did) was necessary to unambiguously get the point across.

Comment: Well, what about someone wanting to implement a compiler for a 6502 processor, that only has 256 bytes of stack? [So, arguments probably would have to go on a separate software controlled stack, since storing registers and return addresses alone would soon eat up 256 bytes of stack].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Who is your question addressed at?

Comment: At "KingsIndian" primarily - the point being that the C (and C++ to a slightly lesser degree) provides a basis for implementing a compiler for almost any target processor. Thus it doesn't regulate how many levels of stack, for example, the code will support - I believe it also doesn't stipulate a minimum or maximum for global variables or for the size the code can be - but of course, if someone writes 200KB of code, and try to run it on a Z80 that has 64KB of address space, it's not going to work - whether is has less than 127 levels of block nesting or not.

Comment: @KingsIndian : look at it this way : in order to suit your needs, the standard would have to require that - no matter how much memory is currently in use - another array of size x can be created. Anything less than that would not be useful, because there's always the chance you end up in a situation where there's no room for the array, and hence undefined behavior is invoked, and that's exactly what you want to avoid. Such a requirement would be impossible to fulfill.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Exactly. What if you're running a function nested 2000 levels deep and all of the parent functions have a 100 element array in them? That would occupy at least 208000 bytes of stack. While this might seem outrageous, someone might have a foolishly written recursive function...

Answer (score 9):

Because C, *the language*, should not be imposing limitations on your available stack size.  C operates in many (many) different environments.  How could it possibly come up with a reasonable number?  Hell, automatic storage duration != stack, a stack is an implementation detail.  C, *the language*, says nothing of a "stack".

The environment decides this stuff, and for good reason.  What if a certain environment implements automatic storage duration via an alternative method which imposes no such limitation?  What if a breakthrough in hardware occurs and all of a sudden modern machines do not require such a limitation?

Should we rev the standard in such an event? We would have to if C, *the language*, specified such implementation details.